# HTTP GET isn't working?

Tags: html, forms, http, post, get

I have a form on a webpage that will submit data in the fields to be processed on another page.

Here is the form:

```
<form align="center" action="submitrivalsconfig.php" method="get">
        <b>PN Operator:</b>
        <select name="PNOp" value="<?php echo $data["PNOp"]?>">
            <option value="=">=</option>
            <option value=">">></option>
            <option value="<"><</option>
            <option value=">=">>=</option>
            <option value="<="><=</option>
        </select>
        <b>PN Value:  </b>
        <input type="number" name="PNValue" value="<?php echo $data["PNValue"]?>" style="width:40px">

        <br><br>

        <b>MEL Operator:</b>
        <select name="MELOp" value="<?php echo $data["MELOp"]?>">
            <option value="=">=</option>
            <option value=">">></option>
            <option value="<"><</option>
            <option value=">=">>=</option>
            <option value="<="><=</option>
        </select>
        <b>MEL Value:</b>
        <input type="number" name="MELValue" value="<?php echo $data["MELValue"]?>" style="width:40px">

        <br><br>

        <b>NDZ Operator:</b>
        <select name="NDZOp" value="<?php echo $data["NDZOp"]?>">
            <option value="=">=</option>
            <option value=">">></option>
            <option value="<"><</option>
            <option value=">=">>=</option>
            <option value="<="><=</option>
        </select>
        <b>NDZ Value: </b>
        <input type="number" name="NDZValue" value="<?php echo $data["NDZValue"]?>" style="width:40px">

        <br><br>

        <b>Fuel Type:</b>
        <input type="text" name="FuelType" value="<?php echo $data["FuelType"]?>" style="width:400px">

        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit Configuration">
    </form>
```

Upon pressing the submit button, I am redirected to the following url:

```
bmratest/minipages/submitrivalsconfig.php?PNOp=%3D&PNValue=54&MELOp=%3D&MELValue=60&NDZOp=%3D&NDZValue=90&FuelType=%27CCGT%27%2C+%27COAL+IN%27%2C+%27COAL+OUT%27%2C+%27OCCGT%27%2C+%27OIL%27
```

Everything seems fine to me so far, but I assigned the data transferred to an array and it outputs blanks, suggesting that the `$_GET` details are blank and it isn't reading the information from the URL.

Comment: You can see the URL so you can see they are not blank. That suggests the problem is with the code you wrote to try to transfer them to an array.

Comment: You should really be using html entities for the arrows, for example, `<option value="<=">&lt;=</option>`. Otherwise the browser may think that the arrows are open/close tags.

Comment: I was thinking the same. So when the new webpage is loaded the GET values are checked if empty, if they are they go to the default value. It seems they always seem to go to the default value for some reason.

Example:
`If (empty($GET_['PNOp'])){
        $data["PNOp"] = $default["PNOp"];
    }Else{
        $data["PNOp"] = $GET_['PNOp'];
    }`

Comment: @CallumLukeVernon — Does everything go to the default values or only the select elements?

Comment: @Quentin i know the arrows inside the quotes are fine, I mean between the opening and closing `option` tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superglobal you are looking for is [called `$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) not `$GET_`.

Comment: DERP! Thanks, I don't understand how I got the underscore in the wrong place. Not like I've been doing these kind of forms for a while now...